# How to resolve conflicting Google play services versions

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am using some native android modules in my Titanium application. Some modules have their own google-play-services.jar included which conflicts with others. Specifically the app is crashed if I include ti.cloudpush module for android push notifications.

Is there any way available to solve this problem? I think this is now quite old and common issue. Following is details of my enviornment:

```
Titanium SDK 5.2.0.GA
Titanium CLI 5.0.6
Target android 6.0
ti.cloudpush 3.4.1
analytics.google 3.1.0
com.sitata.googleplus 1.5.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to solve this problem in the past by selecting one version of google-play-services.jar and forcibly replacing the other versions of the jar file with this one version.

I actually copied the ti.cloudpush module into my project directory so that I can maintain it directly (and keep the proper version of google-play-services.jar checked into my source code repository).

I have not had any problem if I replace the jar file with a newer version.  You can cross-reference your jar file versions against this document: http://www.smorgasbork.com/2015/01/05/google-play-services-sdk-version-history/

Comment: Jason is right. Currently this seems to be the only way to do it.

Comment: Please follow https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-1985 for updates on a final solution to prevent these conflicts.

Comment: Fokke -- I'm not able to see that JIRA issue, even when logged in.  Did it get moved?

Comment: yep. permission violation.